# How to convert the following coordinates to 'shapely' polygon?

Tags: python, opencv, polygon, shapely

I have the coordinates from a list in the following format :

```
[572.71063 453.9848  622.2049  472.86023]
```

where the four numbers correspond to X1, Y1, X2, Y2 coordinates of a rectangle. (X1,Y1 top left corner, X2,Y2 bottom right corner).

I want to convert the list item to a 'shapely' Polygon. The list item is not in the right format, in this case, Polygon to work. So I used the following function

```
brd = Polygon(map(np.squeeze, bb))
```

It does not work. I think the issue with rectangle coordinates is actually not in contours format. I think the contour is supposed to be close.

What is the best way I could convert the rectangle coordinates in the list to shapely polygon?

Comment: and what data expect `shapely`? If it needs only to convert to pairs `[(572.71063 453.9848), (622.2049  472.86023)]` then you could use normal `for`-loop  with `range(0, len(data), 2)` and create list with pairs `(data[i], data[i+1])`. And if contour should be close then maybe you have to only add two first elements at the end `data.append(data[0]), data.append(data[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand problem you need simply this:

```
rect = [572.71063, 453.9848, 622.2049, 472.86023]

X1, Y1, X2, Y2 = rect

polygon = [(X1, Y1), (X2, Y1), (X2, Y2), (X1, Y2)]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimale working code:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rect = [572.71063, 453.9848, 622.2049, 472.86023]

X1, Y1, X2, Y2 = rect

polygon = [(X1, Y1), (X2, Y1), (X2, Y2), (X1, Y2)]

p = Polygon(polygon)

x, y = p.exterior.xy

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]